# Drag and drop ala GMail a gem for Ruby / Rack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, rack

Is there a widget or a gem which implements this feature?
It works only in Chrome and Firefox but it is very cool and no plugins are needed

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/drag-and-drop-attachments-onto-messages.html

Or which would be the best practises to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a plugin, gem or widget to do something like this in supported browsers (Gmail now supports this functionality in Safari, btw) since it's part of the HTML5 API. More on this [here](http://www.webmonkey.com/2009/08/html_5_file_api_brings_drag-and-drop_file_uploads_to_the_web/) and [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/w3c-publish-first-working-draft-of-file-api). Additionally, a quick search for something like "gmail attachment html5" should give you lots of relevant stuff (though I haven't tried).